# AttemptedValue of ValueProviderResult returns wrong value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding, custom-model-binder

I've used ASP.NET MVC5 in my project and I've used custom model binding in it.
when I'm getting the value of IsActive property in my model, I faced a problem.IsActive value must be "true" or "false" but I got **"true,false"**
How can I get the correct value?

```
public class BaseModelBinder<TModel> : IModelBinder where TModel : class, new()
{
    public virtual object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        TModel model = (TModel)bindingContext.Model ?? new TModel();
        ICollection<string> propertyNames = bindingContext.PropertyMetadata.Keys;
        foreach (var propertyName in propertyNames)
        {
            var value = GetValue(bindingContext, propertyName);
            model.SetPropertyValue(propertyName, value);
        }
        return model;
    }

    private string GetValue(ModelBindingContext context, string name)
    {
        name = (context.ModelName == "" ? "" : context.ModelName + ".") + name;

        ValueProviderResult result = context.ValueProvider.GetValue(name);
        if (result == null || result.AttemptedValue == "")
        {
            return "<Not Specified>";
        }
        else
        {
            return (string)result.AttemptedValue;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: AttemptedValue of ValueProviderResult returns wrong value]

> **Summary of my view:**

```
@using System.ComponentModel
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@model Jahan.Blog.ViewModel.ArticleViewModel
  @{
         ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    }
<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Article</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsActive, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsActive)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsActive)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsActiveNewComment, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsActiveNewComment)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsActiveNewComment)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't included you view, but I suspect your using `CheckBoxFor()` which renders 2 inputs with the same name, the first is a checkbox and the second is a hidden input (which is used because unchecked check boxes do not post back and this ensures the default value is posted). The `DefaultModelBinder` ignores the second value if its present.

Comment: I added my summary of view.

Comment: As I suspected. If you look at the html this generates you will see 2 inputs with the `name="IsActiveNewComment"`. If the checkbox is checked, both post back, otherwise only the second (hidden input) posts back. You just need to ignore the second value if it exists

Comment: You are right.But when I change the checkbox, I get a correct value and when I don't change the checkbox value, I get get wrong value. How can I ignore the second value if it exists? Please show me by code.

Comment: I guess you could check the value of `propertyName` in `foreach (var propertyName in propertyNames) {...` and if its the same as the previous value, ignore it (not tested)

Answer (score -1):

According to [Stephen Muecke's descriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26152431/1817640), I modified BindModel method.

```
public virtual object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        TModel model = (TModel)bindingContext.Model ?? new TModel();
        ICollection<string> propertyNames = bindingContext.PropertyMetadata.Keys;
        foreach (var propertyName in propertyNames)
        {
            string value = GetValue(bindingContext, propertyName);
            if (bindingContext.PropertyMetadata[propertyName].ModelType.Name == "Boolean")
            {
                if (value.ToLower() == "true,false" || value.ToLower() == "false,true")
                    value = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.GetValues(propertyName).First();
            }
            model.SetPropertyValue(propertyName, value);
        }
        return model;
    }
```

Comment: Not a proper model binder since it is ignoring ValueProviders and going directly to Request.Form. This will break all kinds of cool things like posting JSON etc.